# solr: read stopword.txt in Custom Handler

Tags: solr

I want to read stopword.txt in my custom handler. How to do that ? I know that this is used in Filtering and can be done from there. But I need to read that list in my Custom UpdateRequestProcessorFactory. Also can I read any other custom file created by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was aware that limitation. I overlooked that you are using about update processor.

I looked into the code, here is an existing  code you can use as example. SolrCoreAware is the interface you are after.

```
public class StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory extends UpdateRequestProcessorFactory implements SolrCoreAware


@Override
public void inform(SolrCore core) {
resourceLoader = core.getResourceLoader();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes that implement org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoaderAware can read files under conf directory. However what it your use case anyway?

looks like xy problem

Comment: I have implemented the ResourceLoaderAware class. But the inform method is not getting called. How to call that method.

Comment: Also if I implmenet ResourceLoaderAware in UpdateRequestProcessorFactory it gives error that  org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoaderAware must be an instance of: [org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharFilterFactory] [org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory] [org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenizerFactory] [org.apache.solr.search.QParserPlugin] [org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType]